# How could I make a tool interactable?

Tags: roblox

I am making a game in Roblox, and I have made multiple tools, which are all items of food. I have made it so they can enter your inventory, but I do not know how to make them useful i.e. eating them. I was wondering how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting out the best solution would be to look for edible items on the Toolbox and possibly inspect their code to learn how they function.

If you would like to make a tool like this yourself you definitely need to acknowledge basic scripting in Lua and learn the inner workings of Roblox itself.

You'd need a Script (I think LocalScript would be better in this scenario) inserted into the tool along with an Animation class, which could also be gathered from the toolbox.

Hope it helps, and sorry for the 6 day "delay",
A stranger on the internet.